# Two-way databinding: Updating textbox not updating bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am databinding a textbox of a `UserControl` to a property as follows.

```
<TextBox Name="txtData" Text="{Binding MyData, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

But when I click the Submit button on the page that hosts the usercontrol after entering some text in the `txtData` textbox of the usercontrol, `userControl.MyData` returns `null`. What can I do to have the `txtData.text` value be assigned to property other than through `TextChanged`event?

Comment: are you sure that the binding is correct? If you set the value of MyData in the constructor of the user control do you see it in the text box? If yes, please share the whole XAML.

Comment: No it is not! I am not getting what is wrong.

Comment: Read about [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) first then if you have no clue...

Comment: @H.B I am following to TwoWay mode as explained there. I don't have to update UI when property changes, but I have to update property when UI changes. So I think I don't have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Is that right?

Comment: @darthvader: First of all you don't need to set the mode to `TwoWay` because it already is, second of all you need to understand how binding sources work and what the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) is. You are right about the interface but that is *not* the issue here. Read the article *fully*.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments you wish to update `userControl.MyData` when the `TextBox.Text` changes.

From the binding perspective `TextBox.Text` is the target and `MyData` is the source so strictly speaking this is a `OnWayToSource` binding (to source => to MyData) - so there should be no need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  But that is not the issue.

The way the binding is currently written, the `MyData` property expects to be found on the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` - is that the case?  You could fix the data context or possibly use some other binding source e.g. ElementName or RelativeSource - difficult to say without seeing more xaml.

You might also consider setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the binding.

Comment: Yes that is the case. `MyData` property expects to be found on the `DataContext` of the `TextBox`